# How to run quarkus tests using certain profile defined in application.properties

Tags: unit-testing, testing, quarkus

Say I have the following in application.properties:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=${db_url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ekycapi}
%dockerrun.quarkus.datasource.url=${db_url:jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/anotherdb}
```

When running in dev mode, I run as "mvn quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.profile=dockerrun"
But what if I want to use the same profile while running the tests? What is the correct syntax for it? Something like "mvn test -Dquarkus.profile=dockerrun"?

Answer (score 2):

Use `quarkus.test.profile` to set the desired test profile. See more config options on  the [all-config page](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config)